# regexMatch to find similar string value

Tags: regex

records kept in SQL database like below:

```
"ItemId": "Facility/Market A/Store 1/Unit 2",

"ItemId": "Facility/Market A/Store 2/Unit 2",
```

the api application allow user to do regexMatch and regexReplace.

I want to replace /Store 1/Unit 2 to /Store 1/Unit 2 New

what is the syntax for regexMatch  ?

Comment: It is not clear what replacing you want to do, maybe you gave typo. Also please show a little of your experiments. Surely you already achieved something like replacing all "Store" by "Shoebox" or something. Please show the code for that. You might also need to show more sample input and some cases where what you search for looks similar, but should NOT be replaced. Otherwise it would be the most obvious solution to do a literal replace `s/searchfor/replaceby/`. It is not clear what your obstacle is.

Comment: @Yunosch i have tried simple one as regexMatch "/Store 1/Unit 2 to /Store 1/Unit 2" to be regexReplace "/Store 1/Unit 2 to /Store 1/Unit 2 New" . not sure if this is correct way or if there is shortcut syntax

Comment: Please [edit] to add that to the question. And please give more details on how you do this and what the undesired result is; ideally in contrast to the desired result.

Comment: Maybe give details what happens if you use the literal search for `/Store 1/Unit 2 to /Store 1/Unit 2` with the literal replacement `/Store 1/Unit 2 to /Store 1/Unit 2 New`. Note that I do not see the thing you want to search for in the sample input you are giving.

Comment: Maybe using more formatting helps with clarity. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help